# smartphone mobile banking application architecture

Tags: mobile, architecture, restful-architecture, banking

My company has decided to develop a mobile banking application for our client. But we are confused in choosing best architecture for mobile banking.
Our requirements are

1. Mobile client- native/hybrid/web-based(using phonegap or any other framework)
2. Server-Tomcat
3. Service layer-REST web services(Jersey)
4. DAO-hibernate/optional

My question is-what will be best architecture for mobile banking using above technologies.